# Methods for GEE ImageCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, references, documentation

Is there a list, or other documentation and resources, with functions that I can put in front of any variable in Google Earth Engine?

I'm not talking about functions that come after 'ee.' but functions after **any** variable. In the example below, I'm using 's2' to Sentinel 2 and found the function *filter* to select what I want from the dataset.

Where can I have the information of functions that I can use after 's2.'?

[image]

Comment: Simple web search for "ee.imagecollection reference" will give you https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection

Comment: What he said.  And those are called "methods", they're specific to the type of object that the variable holds.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot TomazicM and mikewatt!